# apache need twice click

Tags: apache, redirect

I couldn't get a clue.

I have an apache server with a web service.

First I give user a login page, when a user click 'login' button, the page will be redirected to the second page. I saw the url on the search line already changed to the supposed page, but the login page is still there and won't refresh.

Only after I click 'login' button second time, the page will be refreshed. How could it happen?

The same case happens for the every redirect page further, every click, my page will be back to the login page, then only after click 'login' button second time, it will be redirected.

Thanks in advance.
Yang

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: En, at the moment, it looks not about httpd conf. It's something about mason I'm using.